# SQL Join to return data from The Same Column in the same table to two diffrent rows in result (Star Wars Example)

Tags: sql, join, union

Newbie question about joining tables.  I want to retrieve a name from a column **TWICE** in a SQL statement, and I'm running in circles.

I Have two Tables -  "Company" & "People"

Table -"People"

| ID | Name | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Luke | 555-1212 |
| 2 | Leia | 555-1234 |
| 3 | Han | 999-8888 |
| 4 | Anikin | 888-9876 |
| 5 | Obi-wan | 555-1212 |
| 6 | R2-D2 | #% - **!? |

Table - "Company"

| ID | CompanyName | PrimaryContact | AltContact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Speeders R Us | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | Droid Repair World | 6 | 4 |
| 3 | Luke's Second Hand Store | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | Cloak World | 4 | 5 |
| 5 | Ye Old Blaster Shoppe | 3 | 2 |

If I want to get a result that gives BOTH the Contact Names for a Company, How would I do it?

I can get the PrimaryContact to JOIN Properly using something like...

```
SELECT C.*, P.Name as 'Primary' 
FROM `Company` C 
Join People P on  
C.PrimaryContact = P.ID  
WHERE C.ID =3
```

which successfully returns

| ID | CompanyName | PrimaryContact | AltContact | Primary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Luke's Second Hand Store | 1 | 4 | Luke |

But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to modify this SQL to also return "Anikin" as the Alternate Contact.  Is this an example of where a UNION statement would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join to the same table multiple times, just give a new alias every time.

```
Join People P on  C.PrimaryContact = P.ID 

Join People P1 on  C.AltContact = P1.ID 

 Join People altcontact on  C.AltContact = altcontact.ID 

Join People P256 on  C.yetanotheralternateContact = P256.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to to join for ecervy contact another Persons table

```
SELECT C.ID,C.CompanyName, P.Name as 'Primary' , P.Phone As 'primary_Phone', P2.Name on 'Alternative', P2.Phone as 'Alternatibe_Phone
FROM `Company` C 
Join People P on  
C.PrimaryContact = P.ID  
Join People P2 on  
C.AltContact = P2.ID  
WHERE C.ID
```